# Order by in PostgreSQL table with preserving value from row before

Tags: sql, postgresql

So what I basically need is a simple order by, but just preserving the value from column/group before.

For example, in a mixed table, when i do an order by **date** and then **tag**, it gives output like this: [image]

And what i want is the rows with id 2 and 5 and rows with id 4 and 8 to be swapped.

[image]

And the result should be like following.

[image]

The example is a bit simplified, but it should work in general case. So basically when there are multiple rows with same **date**, but different **tag**, it should look at the last row (it's **tag**) of group before by date. If there is a matching **tag** in the following group, that that one should be first, else classic order by **tag** should follow.

Maybe this one is easy, but my SQL experience is quite low, so i don't know how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Here is an example in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cc539/1).

Comment: Please don't provide images, but real data. Currently it is absolutely impossible to copy your data to test certain solutions and we don't want to spend the rare time with retyping your data. Second: Your use case is quite complecated because ordering one group is completely independenty from another. So you need add a ordering criterion. If you have none, it needs to be done in a huge, messy query which cannot be intended just for ordering, I guess.

Comment: I agree. I added an SQL fiddle to assist. Not sure what you mean by ordering criterion?

Comment: Did you try adding a desc in the order by in front of tag column

Comment: Yes, and it would not produce the exact output needed, but more important it would not work in general case. So when i have the date 2020-09-17 for example, when i'm ordering it, i want to look at the group before by date (if there are rows with date 2020-09-15 or even older, whatever the last one is), and put the row on first place that matches the row form the group before on last place.

Comment: @user3315556 that would just reverse the order of mismatch.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver order by useragedate, tag desc will that be an issue?

Comment: @user3315556. Try it in the fiddle and see what happens.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver that is exactly what the OP wants ?

Comment: @user3315556. No, look at rows `9, 8,4`. By the OP's rules they should be  `9,4,8`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Op asks : So basically when there are multiple rows with same date, but different tag, it should look at the last row  (it's tag) of group.

Comment: @user3315556. " If there is a matching tag in the following group, that that one should be first, else classic order by tag should follow."

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with your problem specification for 8 and 4.  *Both* tags are present on the previous day.  So, I see no reason why they should be in an inverse order.

If you want to implement the rule that "Tags on the previous day should be ordered before new tags on this day", then you can use window functions.  What is nice is that you can do this directly in the `ORDER BY`:

```
select t.*
from tagtable t
order by date,
         (lag(date) over (partition by tag order by date) =
          max(date) over (order by date range between unbounded preceding and '1 day' preceding)
         ) desc nulls last,
         Tag;
```

This does *not* change the ordering of 8/4 for the reason specified above.

Also, I don't know if the `key` column is important.  You don't mention it in the question, but perhaps both window functions should be partitioning by the `key` as well.

Finally, this doesn't work in your sql<>fiddle because that uses a rather old version of Postgres.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=645facd4f4db738e615414dd45235924) is a db<>fiddle.

EDIT:

If you really want, you can put the tags from the previous day as a *descending* sort:

```
select t.*
from tagtable t
order by date,
         (lag(date) over (partition by tag order by date) =
          max(date) over (order by date range between unbounded preceding and '1 day' preceding)
         ) desc nulls last,
         (case when lag(date) over (partition by tag order by date) =
                    max(date) over (order by date range between unbounded preceding and '1 day' preceding)
               then tag desc
          end),
         Tag asc;
```

Comment: When you look at the date 2015-09-19, you see the last tag in there was Tag1. So if there is a Tag1 in 2015-09-20, it should go first, which it in the example does. Tag2 was the last value for 2015-09-20, which means for 2015-09-21 if there is a Tag2 on that date, it should go first. So that would influence the swap of 4 and 8.

Generally there could be different values for key, but it's not really important. If i know how to do the proper ordering for one Key, i could do it through different keys.

Comment: @NikolaTomic . .  .In that case, you want a descending sort for the tags that match on the previous day.

Comment: Help with that?

Comment: @NikolaTomic . . . I edited the answer before I made the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
select id, key, tag, date
from tagtable 
order by 
   date, 
   CASE WHEN ( lag(tag) over (order by date)='Tag2') THEN Tag END DESC,
   Tag
```

produces:

```
id  key     tag     date
11  Key1    Tag2    2015-09-15
3   Key1    Tag2    2015-09-16
5   Key1    Tag2    2015-09-17
2   Key1    Tag1    2015-09-17
7   Key1    Tag1    2015-09-18
1   Key1    Tag1    2015-09-19
9   Key1    Tag1    2015-09-20
10  Key1    Tag2    2015-09-20
8   Key1    Tag2    2015-09-21
4   Key1    Tag1    2015-09-21
6   Key1    Tag1    2015-09-22
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cc539/31)

And, yes, it is ugly to have `='Tag2'` in the query.